# Zf2 - Query with join

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to do a join.
But I can not choose the columns returned.

```
public function getDonneesProjet($idProjet)
{
    $idProjet  = (int) $idProjet;
    return $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($idProjet) {
            $select ->join('rapport', 'rapport.id = donnee_factuelle.rapport_id', array('date'))                    
                    ->where("projet_id = $idProjet");
    })->toArray();
}
```

I have all the columns in my table "donnee_factuelle".
But I do not know how to retrieve the "date" column of the table "rapport".

One idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these changes to your query - (remove `->toArray()`)

```
public function getDonneesProjet($idProjet)
{
    $idProjet  = (int) $idProjet;
    return $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($idProjet) {
            $select ->join('rapport', 'rapport.id = donnee_factuelle.rapport_id', array('date'))                    
                    ->where("projet_id = $idProjet");
    });  //->toArray() is removed.
}
```

As this is tablegateway, you need to add the property (`date` - of the `rapport` table), in your Primary (Main) Model file.

Eg:

```
class MODEL_NAME {

    //other properties

    public $date;

    public function exchangeArray($data) {

        //other properties

        $this->date = (!empty($data['date'])) ? $data['date'] : null;
    }

}
```

Only this way you could get the `date` property in the object and the value of it.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code snippet:

```
public function fetchAll() {
        $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()
            ->join('join_table', 'gateway_table.id=join_table.link_id', array ('viewfieldname' => 'joinfieldname'));

        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith ( $select );

        return $resultSet;
    }
```